# create a function to check for all onclick javascript

Tags: javascript, html

SO I' new to javascript, and I am trying to check for 20 buttons on my code, I know how to handle the onclick  to each of them, doing it by their id. however I was wondering if there is a more elegant way to group buttons in categories, for instance, I have 10 buttons that are numbers, and with all of them I need to do the same operation, write them out to a display. So I was wondering if there is way to create a function that could take all the buttons with id that specify numbers, and check when they are clicked and perform the same operation maybe a loop procedure?

so let's say btn1-btn10 are numbers
and the user press btn3, so instead of having a start function to check for all btn1 though 20.. just another field to specify those btn are numbers,  and automatically go to the same function to write it out.

alright thanks for your time.

Comment: Do you have some current work on jsfiddle?

Comment: Are you using jQuery ?

Comment: Look into "event delegation". Give your number buttons a common class.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a little bit confused about your question but you can assign a class to a subset of elements (buttons) so you can listen to click events for this subset of elements. E.g. by defining:

```
<input type="button" id="button1" class="megaButton"></input>
<input type="button" id="button2" class="megaButton"></input>
```

And then listening to click events associated with the class megaButton:

```
var buttons = document.getElementsByClassName("megaButton");
buttons.onclick = methodToHandle; // Handle the click request.
```

Note that the above code snippet may contain an error as I'm more into jQuery, which would solve the problem in a similar manner:

```
$(".megaButton").on("click", function()
{
    // Any button with class megaButton may have been clicked.
    // Grab the id if you wish to know which one was clicked.
    var currId = $(this).attr('id');
});
```

Please clarify your question and or make a proper search and rephrase the question if this is no way near what you've asked. I guarantee that your problem has been solved before, you just need to use the correct key-words when looking.